# Change the font of current buffer in Emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs, fonts, x11

In emacs, I can change the font-size of current buffer by `text-scale-adjust`. However, to change the font, I only find functions like `set-face-font` or `set-frame-font`, which will change the font globally in emacs (or change all buffers' font within current frame).

Is there a function in emacs that only changes the font (default font) of current buffer, while not modifying the fonts in any other buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way, though it has some side effects as it changes the global variable `buffer-face-mode-face`

For example, I want to set current buffer, I can eval this function definition and run it

```
 (defun my-buffer-face-mode-serif ()
   "Sets a fixed width (monospace) font in current buffer"
   (interactive)
   (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Times New Roman"))
   (buffer-face-mode))
```

Comment: Using `buffer-face-set` like in @jmibanez 's answer won't pollute the global variable. Related code in `buffer-face-set`: `(set (make-local-variable 'buffer-face-mode-face) specs)`

Answer (score 5):

As of Emacs 23, you can change the face per buffer via `M-x buffer-face-set`. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FacesPerBuffer . So, taking Firegun's answer, you can use `buffer-set-face` like so:

```
(defun jmi/set-buffer-local-family (font-family)
  "Sets font in current buffer"
  (interactive "sFont Family: ")
  (defface tmp-buffer-local-face 
    '((t :family font-family))
    "Temporary buffer-local face")
  (buffer-face-set 'tmp-buffer-local-face))
```

(NB: This still suffers from the problem that face names themselves are global)

Answer (score 0):

In GNU Emacs, a font is part of a face.  Faces are generally global, so changing the font of a face affects all buffers, by default.

But you can give a face a buffer-local setting, using the functions in `face-remap.el` - see the Elisp manual, node [Face Remapping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html).  Or you can use function `buffer-set-face`, as @jmibanez's answer says.